# Flutter Inspector Issue: Unable to Navigate to Widget Code in Dart File from Widget Mode

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform, inspector

Previously, when I ran the app and turned on the *widget mode* in the *Flutter Inspector*, if I clicked on any widget in the APP, **it would immediately navigate to the code related to that widget element inside the Dart file**. But now, when I click, it only selects the *widget* in the *widget tree*. However, **it doesn't navigate to the related code in the Dart file anymore**.
What could be the possible solution for this?

My expectation is:
If I click on any widget in the app, it will immediately navigate to the code related to that widget element inside the Dart file like previously

Comment: I've found a solution from a YouTube video. Here's the link-
https://youtu.be/oHcjiMGG4ic?si=lrvzPKDnI2IxHfqj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Flutter to the latest version - Flutter 3.16.2 and Dart 3.2.2. The Flutter team has fixed the issue with the Flutter Inspector not showing source code.
Get the latest update at https://github.com/flutter/flutter and you'll be good to go.